# Devise Sign-Up Route End of File Reached Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I've searched all over the internet for an answer to this error, but nothing seems to address it directly or effectively.

I am using Devise in a Rails application and whenever I go to the users/sign_up page and submit the data, it will not submit properly and Rails gives me the error:

"EOFError at /users
end of file reached"

Rails also includes this trace:

```
 rbuf_fill/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb
BUFSIZE = 1024 * 16
def rbuf_fill
  begin
    @rbuf << @io.read_nonblock(BUFSIZE)
  rescue IO::WaitReadable
    if IO.select([@io], nil, nil, @read_timeout)
      retry
    else
      raise Net::ReadTimeout
```

Which I have had no luck following.

From other posts, I believe something may be wrong with the mailer setup, but I've tried every solution recommended and I'm still getting this error. Currently, I have config.mailer_sender = SUPPORT_EMAIL setup in the config/initializers/devise.rb file.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone has, as I've spent a ton of time on this with no luck.